# html table border is not consistent in IE6.0 and firefox

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6

In my html table I have used a `border`. But my border is inconsistent in IE 6.0 and firefox. In IE `border-bottom`'s height is more than expected but in Mozilla it is same on all borders.

Images for Firefox and IE respectively:

[image]
[image]

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td style="width:90%;border:2px solid #3399FF;">this is demo</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Please tell me how to make it consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a IE box model issue to me.
See this http://lloydom.blogspot.com/p/technical-stuff.html and scroll down to the IE 6 BOx model heading