# IE6.0/Firefox browser issue, table border is not same in both browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [html table border is not consistent in IE6.0 and firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305638/html-table-border-is-not-consistent-in-ie6-0-and-firefox)

border in **html table**  is looking different in IE and mozilla . border is same around all sides in **mozilla**  but in IE6.0 it is not same. **border bottom**  is more in length.

Images for Firefox and IE respectively:

[image]
[image]

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td style="width:90%;border:2px solid #3399FF;">this is demo</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

i am not able to figure out what went wrong in this. please help. Thanks

Comment: The asker did not get any answer to his other question. Based on the username I would delete that one and leave this one.

Comment: Just a note, who still using ie6, for me I stopped support it, its officially dead and not supported from Google, Yahoo, MSN, ... etc, and I think less than 3% of world people still using it !

Comment: @Al-Mothafar: Actually, it's 7.9%, but 4.3% is all in China, so the rest of the world is actually around 3.6%. [Check out the IE6 Countdown](http://www.ie6countdown.com/)

Comment: @animuson my ref is w3 schools : http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp , and even it 3.6% its nothing ! that what companies like Google, Facebook, and more said too. you can add a message for visitor to let them now there is something new, and help him to get out from their cave !

Comment: @Al-Mothafar: The w3schools data *only* covers visitors to the w3schools websites. It's not an accurate representation of worldwide browser usage. The IE6 Countdown site is actually run by Microsoft.

Comment: @animuson who believe Microsoft these days :P , anyway I have Google Analytics account and the result what I got is close from that in w3 schools. **EDIT** look at this note from w3s : (The statistics above are extracted from W3Schools' log-files, but we are also monitoring other sources around the Internet to assure the quality of these figures).

Answer (score 1):

I have IE6, and I tried your code and it looks exactly the same as in firefox.

So clearly there is some other code there that is causing the problem. Without seeing that code I am unable to help you.

Here is the image in IE6, with a piece of the about windw with the IE version.

[image: Border in IE6]

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me,May be some other css overwriting your inline css

You can use:

```
<td style="width:90%;border:2px solid #3399FF; !important">this is demo</td>
```